# Regex constraint in rails route

Tags: ruby-on-rails, regex

I have a route to which I am adding a constraint for an integer to be anywhere between 0-2 i.e. the integer can either be 0,1 or 2. I tried something, but that's not helping.

```
Route:
get 'books/:book_type', to: 'books#type', constraints: { book_type: /\d{0,2}/ }
```

Is this right or am I missing something here?

Comment: use `book_type: /[120]/`

Answer (score 1):

`{0,2}` is not a digit between 0 and 2, but 0 to 2 of preceding tokens. (in your case, it is`\d`  - a digit from 0 to 9). You must have meant `[0-2]`.

Comment: yeah `[0-2]` is much better than `[012]`.. :D

Comment: @Arup Lol... Haha, indeed it doesn't make any difference in length.